# If statement considering multiple cells to update multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update one cell based on the value of another cell but this needs to be done across a series of ranges. I am stumped on the code to do this.

This is Vba in excel.

```
Sub Elec()
Dim kw As Range, cells As Range, Response1 As Integer
InputBox ("Update Run Status to No Where the Kw load is less than")

    Set kw = Range("B10:Z10")
    Set cells = Range("B14:Z14")
        If kw < Response1 Then
            For Each cells In kw
            Set cells.Value = "No"
    Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're after something like this:

```
Sub Elec()
    Dim cell As Range, Response1 As Long

    Response1 = Application.InputBox("Update Run Status to No Where the Kw load is less than", , , , , , , 1)

    For Each cell In Range("B10:Z10")
        If cell.Value < Response1 Then cell.Offset(4).Value = "No"
    Next
End Sub
```

where:

- use `Application.InputBox()` instead of `VBA.InputBox()` to force the type of user input: that last `1` is to force *numeric* input
- use `Offset()` property of `Range` object with `4` as row offset parameter and point to the cell four rows below the referenced one